# how to render two forms in one template using a class based view

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-users

I'm using django's built-in User model, but I also have my own Account model which extends it:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    experience = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

in my `admin.py` file:

```
class AccountInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Account
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Accounts'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccountInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

I want it to be that when a User registers they enter this information in, but my issue is getting both the UserForm and AccountForm in the same template/view.

As of now this is my registration view:

```
class UserRegistration(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'registration/registration.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        form.registration_notification()
        login(self.request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))
```

How do I add my AccountForm to this view as well so that I can render both in the template and submit with one button. I've seen people do it with a function based view but is there a way to do it with a class-based view?

I also want the same idea for my UpdateView where a User can update User information, but also Account information. I assume it would follow the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom user model "Extend AbstractUser" since you want to add extra fields and add as many other fields as you want in a single model and avoid making extra queries to the database.

From Django documentation :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    field 1
    field 2
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from myapp.models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('custom_field',)
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: this doesn't work because I already have a User and Account set up. Django says to do this at the start of a project.